# DartEditor reformat source code

Tags: dart, dart-editor

I'm used to Visual Studio 2010 "Format Document" menu option to reformat JavaScript source. Now trying Dart Editor looking for menu option to reformat .dart source code? Is this feature supported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code formatting is WIP and will probably be available soon.

see

- https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=2059
- https://codereview.chromium.org/16562012/

Answer (score 0):

There is no code formatting yet, unfortunately. I am sure this is something that will be added within the end of 2014 or 2015 though.